# How to filter http logs to identify DDOS

Tags: apache, nginx, haproxy, ddos

I would like to be able to look through my haproxy logs and see if I can identify possible abuse to my websites. I am more of a developer than a SysOp so would really appreciate some basic information on how to filter my logs finding a number of occurencies for requests from the same IP addresses, i.e.

```
189.291.289.29 - 105 requests
189.101.89.11  - 85 requests
```